# The logo is not being replaced with hover

Tags: html, css

```css
ul{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.logos{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;

 padding-left: 101px;
 padding-right: 101px;

 list-style: none;
}
.logo{
 padding-right: 40px;
}
.logo:nth-child(4n){
 padding-right: 0px;
}
img{
 width: 260px;
 height: 100px;
}
.hover{
 display: none;
}
.logo-dj:hover{
 display: none;
}
.logo-dj:hover .first-logo-hover{
 display: block;
 width: 260px;
 height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Logos</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet"  href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <ul class="logos">
  <li class="logo logo-dj"><a href="#"><img src="img/logo-1-jpg.jpg"></a></li>
  <li class="hover first-logo-hover"><a href="#"><img src="img/colourful-logo-1.jpg"></a></li>
  <li class="logo logo-gadgets"><a href="#"><img class="second-logo" src="img/logo-gadgets-jpg.jpg"></a></li>
  <li class="logo logo-gopro"><a href="#"><img class="third-logo" src="img/logo-gopro-jpg.jpg"></a></li>
  <li class="logo logo-vive"><a href="#"><img class="fourth-logo" src="img/vive.jpg"></a></li>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to replace the first logo with a colorful version of it on :hover, but it's not working. It feels like I'm missing out some basic point but I can't figure out what it is, can anybody help me please?

Sorry if it's a dumb question.

Comment: You can use placeholder.com to get free images for testing

Answer (score 0):

Removed major parts of the code just to show how you can change logo on hover simply.

```css
.logo {
background-image : url('https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/logo-2.png?w=300');
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
.logo:hover {
background-image: url('https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Logo-1.png?w=300');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Logos</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet"  href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <ul class="logos">
  <li class="logo"><a href="#"></li>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: kindly close the question if this is what you were looking for.